# Como puedo mostrar informacion de una base de datos en Firebase en React Native dentro de un <Text>?

Tags: firebase, react-native

**¿Cómo Leer datos desde una RealTimeDatabase  en [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native)?**

Hola, estoy intentando leer datos desde una base de datos realtime en [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) pero no logro hacer que se renderice esta información en un **`Text`** component. solo puedo mostrar la informacion del objeto por **`console.log`** y descomponerlo pero en el render de la pantalla no se muestra la información.

```
class UserProfileScreen extends Component<Props> {

state = {
 dataUser : []
}

componentDidMount(){
 const { uid } = firebaseAuth.currentUser
 this.getUserRef().child(uid).once('value',function(snapshot){
  dataUser = snapshot.val()
  console.log(dataUser.username)
 })
}

getUserRef = () => {
  return firebaseDatabase.ref('users')
}

render(){
 const {dataUser} = this.state
 return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{dataUser.username}</Text>
  </View>
  )
 }
}
```

---

***Objeto obtenido de la base de datos mostrado por consola***

> [image: Objeto obtenido de la base de datos mostrado por consola]

---

***Emulador android***

[image: emulador android]

**¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respuesta corta**

Hay que usar `setState` en vez de mutar el estado directamente.

```
componentDidMount(){
  const { uid } = firebaseAuth.currentUser
  this.getUserRef().child(uid).once('value',function(snapshot){
    this.setState({ dataUser: snapshot.val() })
  })
}
```

**Respuesta larga**

Un **concepto clave** en React (y por consiguiente, en React Native también) es el de **inmutabilidad**.

En particular, el estado interno de los componentes de React (el `state`) debe ser **inmutable**, es decir, no debe ser mutado/modificado directamente sino reemplazado cada vez que queremos hacer un cambio. Para esto, React nos provee el método `setState` (documentado [aquí](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)) que se encarga de actualizar el mismo y que genera como consecuencia un nuevo **render** que hace que los cambios se vean reflejados en la UI.

Comment: Ahora entindo mejor las cosas que bueno ver tu respuesta por estos lados :D